# Clojure "same value" allocation

Tags: performance, memory, clojure

Say I have the following code

`(let [a (some-function 3)
       b (some-function (+ 1 2))
       c a]
   (= a b))`

Suppose some-function returns a very big data structure (say one million sized array)

First question: how much memory will clojure allocate? Will it allocate memory for each of these 3 vectors or they will share the same data structure?

Second question (closely related): how fast would it be to compare them? Will `=` iterate over each element or not?

This simplified example may look dumb but there are similar real life situations where this matters a lot like

```
(map some-function [1 23 1 32 1 44 1 5 1 1 1 1])
```

EDIT

in my specific case, `some-function` returns a `conj` of two sets which may be very big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Whether `a` and `b` share the structure depends entirely on what `some-function` does. It's impossible to answer without any details. `c` and `a` will be bound to the same value, so no additional memory allocation for `c`.
2. In general, semantics and behavior of `=` depend on what values you compare. If you compare collections, then yes, `=` will iterate through each element until it either exhausts them, or finds the first pair of unequal ones.

Additionally:

`=` will first check if the objects being compared are the same (reference equality,) so comparison of `a` and `c` will be instant.

While it's impossible to say for certain if different `some-function` invocation return the same or different structure, chances are without memoization they will be different. Just wrap your `some-function` using `memoize` to be certain there is no double allocation (of course assuming your `some-function` is pure.) As simple as

```
(def some-function (memoize some-function))
```

Comment: So even if `a` and `c` share the same value and structure in memory, comparing them is slow?

Comment: I just added some information in my question. Thanks for the help in advance